# Как создать строку из массива байтов типа int?

Tags: java

Например, имеется массив из N элементов, в котором индексы i и i+1 образуют по таблице UTF-8 русский символ. Как их объединить и на основе этого создать строку?

Пример:

array[0] = 208;

array[1] = 144;

По таблице UTF-8 dec: А - 208 144

Такое получилось после того, как из строки считал байты и перевел их в массив int.

CODE:

```
    String sKey = LFSR();
    System.out.println("[PSP]: key: " + sKey); // output: 10011010

    byte[] txt = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] key = sKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] res = new byte[txt.length];

    int[] bytes = new int[txt.length];
    // Шифруем текст
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; ++i) {
        res[i] = (byte) (txt[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
    }

    // здесь выводит иероглифы из-за того, что байты отрицательные и они съедаются. 
    System.out.println("Зашифрованный текст:" + new String(res, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 

    // Расшифровка текста
    for (int i = 0; i < txt.length; ++i) {
        res[i] = (byte) (res[i] ^ key[i % key.length]);
        bytes[i] = res[i] & 0xff; // восстанавливаю байты, избавляюсь от отрицательных
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(bytes[i] + " ");
    }

    // первоначальный текст
    System.out.println("Расшифрованный текст:" + new String(res, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Если у вас там `int`, а не `byte`, то значение можно хранить одним числом -- `1040` (http://wm-school.ru/html/html_utf_cyrillic.html)

Comment: @gil9red, понял, а как можно перевести UTF-8 dec в UNICODE число?

Comment: @VitaljaB., [алгоритм кодирования в Вике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), ну а вам его нужно перевернуть в алгоритм декодирования (на Си это очень просто, наверное на java тоже)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение вопроса перекодировки:** (`UTF-8 decimal` `->` `Unicode`)

```
class UnicodeUtils {
    static int[] convertUtf8DecimalToUnicode(int[] utf8DecimalCodePoints) {
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

        int byteShift = 0;
        int accumulatingUnicodeIndex = 0;
        for (int utf8DecimalCodePoint : utf8DecimalCodePoints) {
            switch (utf8DecimalCodePoint & 0b1111_0000) {
                case 0b1000_0000:
                case 0b1001_0000:
                case 0b1010_0000:
                case 0b1011_0000:
                    --byteShift;
                    int significantBits = (utf8DecimalCodePoint & 0b11_1111) << (byteShift * 6);
                    accumulatingUnicodeIndex = accumulatingUnicodeIndex | significantBits;
                    break;

                case 0b1100_0000:
                case 0b1101_0000:
                    byteShift = 1;
                    accumulatingUnicodeIndex = getSignificantBits(utf8DecimalCodePoint, byteShift);
                    break;

                case 0b1110_0000:
                    byteShift = 2;
                    accumulatingUnicodeIndex = getSignificantBits(utf8DecimalCodePoint, byteShift);
                    break;

                case 0b1111_0000:
                    byteShift = 3;
                    accumulatingUnicodeIndex = getSignificantBits(utf8DecimalCodePoint, byteShift);
                    break;

                default:
                    accumulatingUnicodeIndex = utf8DecimalCodePoint;
                    break;
            }

            if (byteShift == 0) {
                result.add(accumulatingUnicodeIndex);
                accumulatingUnicodeIndex = 0;
            }
        }

        return result.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
    }

    private static int getSignificantBits(int utf8DecimalCodePoint, int utf8DecimalByteNumber) {
        int utf8ServiceBits = utf8DecimalByteNumber + 2;
        int significantBitsMask = 0b1111_1111 >>> utf8ServiceBits;
        int significantBitsShifts = utf8DecimalByteNumber * 6;
        return (utf8DecimalCodePoint & significantBitsMask) << (significantBitsShifts);
    }

    static String conventUnicodeToString(int[] unicodeIndexes) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(unicodeIndexes.length);
        for (int i : unicodeIndexes) {
            stringBuilder.append(Character.toChars(i));
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] utf8Decimal = {48, 57, 97, 122, 65, 90, 208, 176, 209, 143, 208, 144, 208, 175, 209, 145, 208, 129}; // 09azAZаяАЯёЁ
        int[] unicodeIndexes = UnicodeUtils.convertUtf8DecimalToUnicode(utf8Decimal);
        System.out.println(UnicodeUtils.conventUnicodeToString(unicodeIndexes));
    }
}
```

---

**Решение вопроса с перекодировкой:** (со сдвигом на 20, по результатам общения в комментариях)

```
class EncodingUtils {
    static byte[] encode(byte[] originalBytes) {
        byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[originalBytes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < originalBytes.length; ++i) {
            encodedBytes[i] = (byte) (originalBytes[i] + 20);
        }
        return encodedBytes;
    }

    static byte[] decode(byte[] encodedBytes) {
        byte[] decodedBytes = new byte[encodedBytes.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < encodedBytes.length; ++i) {
            decodedBytes[i] = (byte) (encodedBytes[i] - 20);
        }
        return decodedBytes;
    }
}

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] originalBytes = {-128, -10, 0, 10, 127};
        byte[] encodedBytes = EncodingUtils.encode(originalBytes);
        byte[] decodedBytes = EncodingUtils.decode(encodedBytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но к сожалению, у меня массив из чисел utf-8 dec, а не из юникодов

Comment: @VitaljaB., я вас понял, сейчас попробую накидать простенький конвертер.

Comment: @VitaljaB., я обновил ответ, попробуйте, пожалуйста. Если будет работать, то отрефакторю этот страшненький код :)

Comment: протестировал. в выводе: исходная фраза, которую надо было зашифровать :D

Comment: @VitaljaB., а что не так? :) У вас ведь последний вопрос звучал как utf8 dec транслировать на таблицу индексов unicode, `UnicodeUtils.convertUtf8DecimalToUnicode`, как раз, этим и занимается.

Comment: да. у меня есть зашифрованный текст в виде таких символов: ������� и я хотел его привести к более читабельному виду [А-я], заметив, что массив с байтами дает русские символы

Comment: @VitaljaB., а что значит зашифрованный (чем он зашифрован)? Или вы под шифрованием, на самом деле, имеете в виду encoding, т.е. то, что они перекодированы в utf-8 dec? Просто я все еще не понимаю, что не так :)
Или вы, наоборот, хотите исходный текст перевести в utf-8 dec?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105973/discussion-between-vitalja-b-and-stateitprimitive).

Answer (score 1):

Символ `А` имеет значение `1040` -> `0000010000010000` (2 байта):

- `00000100` -- значение 4
- `00010000` -- значение 16

Небольшой тест:

```
byte[] bytes = {(byte) 4, (byte) 16};
System.out.println(ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getChar());
// А
```

По такому же принципу получаем слово:

```
int[] array = {4, 31, 4, 64, 4, 56, 4, 50, 4, 53, 4, 66};
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2) {
    byte[] bytes = {(byte) array[i], (byte) array[i+1]};
    builder.append(
        ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getChar()
    );
}
System.out.println(builder);
// Привет
```

Comment: С моим массивом вывелись китайские иероглифы. результат есть. Есть небольшое сомнение, что строка 
    byte[] bytes = {(byte) array[i], (byte) array[i+1]};  
может съедать байты, ведь там значение от [-128; 127], а у меня есть значения и 208, 209. В какой кодировке у вас пример?

Comment: Самая первая пара у меня: 208 156 в таблице UTF-8 это М ее юникод - 1052, вот что-то не сходится

Answer (score 1):

Рабочая функция перекодировки (на Си), возвращает количество успешно перекодированных UCS, при ошибке по указателю `utf_err` пишет индекс + 1 первого ошибочного  входного элемента последовательности UTF-8 (если ошибок нет, пишет туда 0), может кому-то окажется полезной
(по крайней мере алгоритм)

```
#ifndef T
#define T  char
#endif


size_t
convert_utf8_to_ucs (T utf8[], uint32_t ucs[], size_t ucs_size,  
                     size_t *utf_err)
{
  size_t n = 0,
    i = 0,
    dummy;

  if (!utf_err)
    utf_err = &dummy;
  *utf_err = 0;

  while (utf8[i]) {
    if (n < ucs_size) {
      uint32_t uc = utf8[i++] & 0xff; // utf-8 is byte coded

      if (uc < 128)
        ucs[n++] = uc; // ascii
      else {
        if (uc < 0xC1 || uc > 0xF7) {
          //  RFC 3629 permits only up to 4 bytes coding
          *utf_err = i;
          break;
        }
        size_t nb = 1; // 1 aux byte for the begin;
        for (int i = 5; uc & (1 << i); nb++, i--);
        uc &= ((1 << (7 - nb)) - 1);   // high bits of UCS

        while (nb--) {
          uint32_t t = utf8[i++];
          if ((t & 0xC0) != 0x80) {
            *utf_err = i;
            return n;     // error utf-8 coding
          }
          uc = ((uc << 6) | (t & 0x3F));
        }
        ucs[n++] = uc;
      }
    } else {
      *utf_err = i + 1;
      break;
    }
  }

  return n;
}
```